# IIS 6 getting "Page Not Found" after applying SSL

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate

I am setting up SSL certificates on a development environment using IIS 6 on W2k3.

I have a directory called login with a single page `login.asp` which I would like only viewable over SSL.

So before installing or applying SSL permissions, the page is viewable through a browser. I can browse the page and it redirects etc. and all is good. However Basic Authentication is Base64 encoded so I want to secure the traffic from this page only.

I have created a dummy certificate in `makecert`, installed it and added it to IIS. IIS is happy that it is trusted. I have selected the directory of `login` and child files to "Require SSL channel". When I refresh my browser on `login/login.asp` I get a "404: Page Not Found" in IE 8. So 2 issues here

1. The page is now unviewable when using HTTPS.
2. They must manually type the HTTPS (minor inconvenience for now)

If I turn off "Require SSL Channel" from IIS, it works again.

What part of the process am I missing as I have followed several tutorials on installed SSL certificates, but still come across this barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have investigated this problem a lot more thoroughly, I thought I'd respond.

The problem is that the page now expects to only be requested as HTTPS. If you require to automatically switch to HTTPS when requesting HTTP, I did this by forcing any 401.3 errors (in the Custom Errors tab of the site) to a specific URL, which then changed the http:// to https:// for any incoming request.

Looking at articles on Google, you can either do it in a ASP/.NET etc or Javascript.

Also I found the `selfssl.exe` in the IIS 6.0 Resource Kit to be much more user friendly than `makecert.exe`. Very very simple to use.